# Adding mute button to application in android?

Tags: android, media-player

I my game application am using musics. I need mute and unmute button to put mob i silent mode.
Music runs in every activity like playing game and checking score.But mute button is added in menu activity.
I googled didn't get any exact result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use audio manager and set volume

```
 AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(ctx.AUDIO_SERVICE);
 audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd choose to set the volume to 0 (mute) or 1 (unmute) with `MediaPlayer.setVolume(float volumeLeft, float volumeRight)`. Also preserves the users volume settings. Trigger by `Button` is easily achieved with `onClickListener()`.

Comment: i cant value for every media player am using...media players are running in different activity.

Comment: Well, I'm working on an audio based app, too. I implemented

`AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);`

Had the disadvantage of altering the users settings. I avoid stuff like that, so I switched to the method above. If I'd be using more instances I'd put them in a publicly available array for "batch"-processing.

Comment: How can I unmute and resume to previous vol